# Is there a way to make `gnss-sdr` work with USRP B210 showing the PVT solution?

Tags: usrp, gnss

`gnss-sdr` seems to be working, but never show coordinates or synchronization with any satellite.

I know that GPSDO included with my USRP only works with GPS ANT connection so, how can i specify to `gnss-sdr` to use GPS ANT connection?

I'm using the configuration file provided by the `gnss-sdr` official website for USRP devices.

My hw.

- USRP B210.
- Active antenna.
- Taidacent Bias-Tee.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that GPSDO included with my USRP only works with GPS ANT connection so, how can i specify to gnss-sdr to use GPS ANT connection?

You don't. the GPS ANT connection goes to to the GPSDO only, not to the SDR. You will need another GPS antenna connected to RF A or RF B (or the same antenna, if you don't mind losing the use of the GPSDO temporarily).

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. If I understand, it is necessary the use of 2 GPS antennas by connecting one of them to the GPS ANT port and the other one to the RX A or B, then execute my configuration file with `gnss-sdr`. Is that right?